# Unity - Clicking on one object activates others

Tags: c#, click, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a Minesweeper + clicker/idle game for practice. For now, I can't get the clicking to work properly. I spawned in all objects through code meaning they are all the same prefabs but at different locations. When I click them the code activates for all of them and all of the tiles change to being open. I am not sure if I'm using the wrong click function here, as I know there is also an `OnMouseDown()` function instead of `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` but the only one where the code activates is in the second one.

```
public class TileClick : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject openTile;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {    
     }    

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             Instantiate(openTile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
             Object.Destroy(this.gameObject);
         }
     }      
 }
```

That's my clicking detection. While it does detect clicks, as I said before, it detects them for ALL tiles and activates them all. I only want it to activate on one of them. I've seen RayCasting stuff but I really need more explanation on how that thing works (if that's the solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `TileClick` script component is attached to your prefab, then for every tile you instantiate, you have a corresponding `TileClick` component attached.

When you click, the input is detected by all of these blocks simultaneously, and each of them calls `Instantiate` but the `transform.position` is the one corresponding to the tile that makes the call. This is why it seems like all the tiles open up simultaneously, because you are, in fact, instantiating an "open" tile on each of them every time you click.

You should keep all your user input code in a separate `MonoBehaviour`, and attach that to a single empty `GameObject` in your scene. For detecting the hit, you should attach a `2DCollider` component to your tile prefab (you can decide the type according to the shape of your tiles), and then just use a simple RayCast in your user input code to instantiate an "open" tile at the position where the hit occurs:

```
void Update () {
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),
                                         Vector2.zero);

    if(hit.collider != null)
    {
       Instantiate(openTile, 
                   hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position,
                   Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

I highly recommend understanding how RayCast works since it is a very useful tool. Here's a good place to start: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html

Comment: While that does answer my question, I soon realized that I could figure out instead how to fix up my OnMouseDown function. Turns out, my camera was just too close so that's why it didn't work. Thanks for the help anyways!